# Building .net 4.0 code with TFS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

I have TFS 2012 installed. I want to setup gated checkins on TFS 2012 for asp.net MVC code that needs to be built in .net 4.0. What is the way to do this?

I assumed TFS 2012 to be the controller and TFS 2010 to be the build agent. However, when I tried to connect the TFS 2010 Build Agent to the TFS 2012 team project Collection from the Build Agent box which is a  differnt machine, I got a message asking me to upgrade to TFS 2012. Isn't that how I would need to do it if I want to set up another machine as my build agent? Point the build agent to the default controller, which in this case is the TFS 2012 box

Will a TFS2012 build agent be able to build code in .net 4.0 that will be deployed on a server that has only .net 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must upgrade the build agents to TFS2012, you cannot mix your TFS tiers on different versions.

Yes, if you have a Build Agent with TFS 2012 (and VS 2012, if needed), you can still build .Net 4.0 only assemblies for deployment. This is exactly how I use TFS.

Assemblies are built targeting the .Net version in the "Target Framework" of the Project file, not what's installed on the server. A later C# compiler might be used if you update visual studio, but that won't cause a deployment issue.

Comment: TFS 2012 Update 3 will allow mixing TFS2010 and 2012 build agents against a TFS2012upd2 server.

But to add to the OP's Q, tfs 2012 will happily build .NET 2, 3, 3.5, 4 and 4.4 for you.

Comment: @jessehouwing Is that an Update 3 Build Controller then? Seen as though the Agent is 2010 and the App is Update 2.

Comment: TFS2012Upd2 App, TFS2010sp1+fc BC and Agent

Comment: That is great to hear. Since .net 4.5 and 4.0 are not exactly side by side compatible I was wondering how that worked. my build controller currently only has .net 4.5 so when building on there wont the assemblies of 4.5 be used? The .NET Framework 4.5 replaces the .NET Framework 4. When you install the .NET Framework 4.5 on a system that has the .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced. So my deployment now has 4.5 assemblies. How does that work on a server with only .net 4.0 ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx

Comment: You don't deploy the Microsoft .Net assemblies from your build server though.

Comment: Hi Dave, I am not deploying the binaries from the build box, but then when I do a get latest on my dev box and publish it from there, where I only have .net 4.0, I get an error: "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 1):

Seems this problem was fixed with Update 2 of TFS 2012:

Can take a look at this site:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/04/04/vs-tfs-2012-2-update-2-released-today.aspx